Bijective polynomial from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$
I'm looking for bijective polynomial functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Being that such one, let it be $f$, needs to be surjective, it has an odd degree. Since it has only one zero, it can be decomposed as : $f(x) = c(x-a)^{2k+1}(x^2 + a_1x + b_1)...(x^2 + a_nx + b_n)$ with $a_i^2 < 4b_i$ for each $i \in [1,...,n]$.
Are those all bijective?

You have to prevent the quadratic factors from having roots

I forgot that, of course. I edited.

The polynomials with such a decoposition are exactly the ones that have odd degree and only one real zero counted without multipicity, but the bijective ones are exactly the strictly monotone polynomials. It's therefore clear that some of the former ar not in the latter, see for instance $f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+5000$.

OK. So now, the question is : is there a simple expression of those which are strictly monotone?

I think you want to write something similar to what you have, but for the derivative of the polynomial -- you want an even degree polynomial with no roots or one root of any multiplicity.

For your question, the answer is no, there exist polynomials of that form that are not bijective. For a method that generate bijective polynomials, see the addendum.
Let $g(x) = (x-a)^{2k+1}$. Choose $x_1, x_2 > a$, $x_1 \neq x_2$, then $g(x_1),g(x_2) > 0$. Denote $g(x_1)$ and $g(x_2)$ as $g_1$ and $g_2$. Let $r_1=g_1^{-1/n},r_2=g_2^{-1/n}$. Choose any constant $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\epsilon < r_1,r_2$. Then there exists a unique parabola $a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1$ that goes through point $(x_1,r_2)$ and $(x_2,r_1)$ with the minimum value $\epsilon$. Then the function $f(x) = g(x)(a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1)^n=a_1^ng(x)(x^2+(b_1/a_1)x + c_1/a_1)^n$ satisfies the given form. Furthermore $f(x_1)/f(x_2) = g_1/g_2\cdot(r_2/r_1)^n = 1$ despites $x_1 \neq x_2$ therefore $f(x)$ is not bijective.
Addendum
A polynomial is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ iif its derivative doesn't change sign on $\mathbb{R}$. So if you want to generate a bijective polynomial, choose a non-negative or non-positive polynimal $P$ and take its integral.
For example let $P = x^6 + (x^2-3)^2 + 1$, then your bijective polynomial would be $\displaystyle \int P = \frac{x^7}{7} + \frac{x^5}{5}-2x^3+10x+C$

As your example suggests, a non-negative polynomial is a sum of squares. In fact, it's a sum of two squares. So the answer is take $ \int (g(x)^2+h(x)^2)$. See Writing Positive Polynomials as Sums of (Few) Squares

This answer seems a little clumsy; perhaps someone can improve on it.
You need the polynomial to be monotonic, so the derivative has to be non-negative (or non-positive). Therefore:$$
f'(x)=k \prod_i (x^2 + a_i x + b_i)\\
a_i^2 \le 4 b_i
$$
This allows for the derivative to touch $0$ but never to cross it.
We can remove the inequality by writing:
$$
f'(x)=k \prod_i ((x - r_i)^2 + c_i^2)
$$
Then, you can expand $f'(x)$ into a polynomial and integrate it, and add an arbitrary constant. There's probably a more clever way to get there.
